# SQL High Availability in MS Azure

Tags: sql, azure

I am looking at ways I can mitigate outages during Azure maintainance using SQL stacks in availability groups.

Coming up with an HA architecture for SQL 2012 on Azure threw up the following observations;

I originally considered 3 options for HADR as DB Mirroring, AlwaysOn FCI & AlwaysOn Availability Groups until it became apparent that FCI is reliant on shared storage - doable but certainly a single point of failure as this storage cannot be spread across Azure availability groups.

AlwaysOn Availbility Groups is possible but only through Enterprise licensing which puts a factor of x5 on the monthly run rate.

So unless I've missed something, unless you're prepared to spend the bucks on Enterprise SQL, you are constrained to DB mirroring - have I got this correct ?

Thanks,

SJM

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark as answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to accomplish High availability for SQL in Azure.

1. As it sounds like you are rolling IaaS, I would suggest reading this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2014/08/18/sql-server-high-availability-in-windows-azure-iaas.aspx
2. If you choose, I find PaaS solutions easier to manage, I would run with SQL Azure and use the geo-replication features.  More details can be found at the following link: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/03/azure-sql-database-standard-geo-replication/